# How to connect to the server in android development using Phonegap?

Tags: php, android, mysql, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new to mobile development. I am given with an Android project to develop with PhoneGap. I have just successfully installed PhoneGap on eclipse. Now I am wondering whether development with Phonegap allows server communication with php.

I am basically a web developer with intermediate knowledge of PHP and MySQL. I am aware that mobile devices are slower than desktops/laptops and most likely to have a slower bandwidth connection. In this case, will this be effective to use PHP as a server side language and MySQL as my choice of database ?

In web applications, I used to create an include file, header and footer pages. Include file with server connection code, header file with js and css links for the header and footer with js and css files for the footer content. I hope most of the web devs here do the same. Can this method be used with phonegap mobile applications as well ?

I did searched over the internet to find a solution for my questions, but I couldn't find anything specific or particular solution for this.

Note - The mobile application project I am working on requires to contact the server very frequently as it is for a shopping portal and I am going to use Jquery Mobile for the application UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to have PHP in your phonegap application. You can however, call .php pages that are on your server to get data back. You make an ajax request and hand the results via javascript. Using jQuery is the easiest in my opinion. Take a look at the docs and examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Examples are all the way at the bottom.

Comment: Hi Dom, Thanks for your answer. I would like to know what database we can use with phonegap. MySQL ?

Comment: Using the phonegap API you can use the sqlite database. If you are calling you PHP page via ajax to return you data from a database, well, the world is your oyster. You can use any DB you want. Here are the docs for the API into sqlite: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Comment: Wow, thanks. What is the usual way that android developers make server calls to fetch data ? Is it an alien's way to use PHP pages?

Comment: I don't know how Android developers make server calls. Android developers use Java and I refuse to use it.

Comment: okay, so usually in phonegap you use php ? or any other language ?

Comment: In phonegap I use jQuery to make an ajax call to php scripts on my server.